# How to get mod_pagespeed working with SSL

Tags: mod-pagespeed

I've got mod_pagespeed installed under `apache2/php5-fpm` and it's working fine on my domain that isn't using SSL (it's combining css and js no probs), however when I access the SSL version of the same site, it no longer works. I've tried setting the variable:

```
ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable
```

But it still is not working. The site is behind basic auth security, would this matter?

I can see in the response headers under the SSL version of the site that `mod_pagespeed` is there, but it's not working it's magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does accessing resources require authentication? If so, then mod_pagespeed probably is not able to access them (it just does an http fetch for resources to rewrite).

Are the same resources available on http? If so, you're best bet might be [MapOriginDomain](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#mapping_origin):

```
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain http://www.example.com/ https://www.example.com/
```

This will fetch all resources with HTTP even when the page is requested with HTTPS. So this would avoid the authentication issue.

See also, https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support for more help with various HTTPS issues.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, also make sure you have added the directory for the `ModPagespeedSslCertFile` in your config file.

Check "Configuring SSL Certificates" at
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support